# Passing calculated variable to another View

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-view

I am trying to create my own grid, which resizing to every element. It's okay with that. Here is a code

```
GeometryReader { geo in
            let columnCount = Int((geo.size.width / 250).rounded(.down))
            let tr = CDNresponse.data?.first?.translations ?? []
            let rowsCount = (CGFloat(tr.count) / CGFloat(columnCount)).rounded(.up)
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<Int(rowsCount), id: \.self) { row in // create number of rows
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<columnCount, id: \.self) { column in // create columns
                            let index = row * columnCount + column
                            if index < (tr.count) {
                                VStack {
                                    MovieCellView(index: index, tr: tr, qualities: $qualities)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But since I don't know the exact number of elements and their indices, I need to calculate them in view.

```
let index = row * columnCount + column
```

And that's the problem - if I pass them as usual (`MovieCellView(index: index  ... )`) when the index changing, the new value is not passed to view.
I cannot use @State and @Binding, as I cannot declare it directly in View Builder and can't declare it on struct because I don't know the count. How to pass data correctly?

Code of `MovieCellView`:

```
struct MovieCellView: View {
    @State var index: Int
    @State var tr: [String]
    @State var showError: Bool = false
    @State var detailed: Bool = false
    
    @Binding var qualities: [String : [Int : URL]]
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

**The most simple example**
Just added `Text("\(index)")` in VStack with MovieCellView and `Text("\(index)")` in `MovieCellView` body. Index in VStack always changing, but not in MovieCellView.
[image: Result]
It is necessary to clarify, my application is on a macOS and the window is resized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none of the answers worked, and only one worked half, I solved the problem myself. You need to generate a Binding, and then just pass it

```
var videos: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            let columnCount = Int((geo.size.width / 250).rounded(.down))
            let rowsCount = (CGFloat((CDNresponse.data?.first?.translations ?? []).count) / CGFloat(columnCount)).rounded(.up)
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<Int(rowsCount), id: \.self) { row in // create number of rows
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(0..<columnCount, id: \.self) { column in // create 3 columns
                            let index = row * columnCount + column
                            if index < ((CDNresponse.data?.first?.translations ?? []).count) {
                                MovieCellView(translation: trBinding(for: index), qualities: qualityBinding(for: (CDNresponse.data?.first?.translations ?? [])[index]))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private func qualityBinding(for key: String) -> Binding<[Int : URL]> {
        return .init(
            get: { self.qualities[key, default: [:]] },
            set: { self.qualities[key] = $0 })
    }
    private func trBinding(for key: Int) -> Binding<String> {
        return .init(
            get: { (self.CDNresponse.data?.first?.translations ?? [])[key] },
            set: { _ in return })
    }



struct MovieCellView: View {
    @State var showError: Bool = false
    @State var detailed: Bool = false
    @Binding var translation: String
    
    @Binding var qualities: [Int : URL]
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution (test code) to your issue of passing calculated variable to another View.
I use an ObservableObject to store the information needed to achieve what you are after.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class MovieCellModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var columnCount: Int = 0
    @Published var rowCount: Int = 0
    
    // this could be in the view 
    func index(row: Int, column: Int) -> Int {
        return row * columnCount + column
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var mcModel = MovieCellModel()
    @State var qualities: [String : [Int : URL]] = ["":[1: URL(string: "https://example.com")!]] // for testing
    let tr = CDNresponse.data?.first?.translations ?? [] // for testing
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<Int(mcModel.rowCount), id: \.self) { row in // create number of rows
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0..<mcModel.columnCount, id: \.self) { column in // create 3 columns
                                if mcModel.index(row: row, column: column) < (tr.count) {
                                    VStack {
                                        MovieCellView(index: mcModel.index(row: row, column: column), tr: tr, qualities: $qualities) 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.onAppear {
                    mcModel.columnCount = Int((geo.size.width / 250).rounded(.down))
                    mcModel.rowCount = Int((CGFloat(tr.count) / CGFloat(mcModel.columnCount)).rounded(.up))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct MovieCellView: View {
    @State var index: Int

    @State var tr: [String]
    @Binding var qualities: [String : [Int : URL]]
    
    @State var showError: Bool = false
    @State var detailed: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(index)").foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have same index for each cell using this solution

Comment: yes sorry, I did not see that. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This saves me from the main advantage of my grid - element swapping and dynamic resizing.

Comment: does this means this is not working for you?

Comment: Yes, because columnCount and rowCount don't changing

Comment: hmm, I' missing some understanding here. Where would you like the columnCount and rowCount to change?

Comment: My app is for macOS, and when the window resizes, they changes.

Answer (score 0):

The only variable that changes outside of a `ForEach` in your `index` calculation is `columnCount`. `row` and `column` are simply indices from the loops. So you can declare `columnCount` as a `@State` variable on the parent view, hence when it changes, the parent view will update and hence all of the cells will also update with the new `columnCount`.

```
@State private var columnCount: CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        columnCount = Int((geo.size.width / 250).rounded(.down))
        let tr = CDNresponse.data?.first?.translations ?? []
        let rowsCount = (CGFloat(tr.count) / CGFloat(columnCount)).rounded(.up)
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(0..<Int(rowsCount), id: \.self) { row in // create number of rows
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<columnCount, id: \.self) { column in // create 3 columns
                        let index = row * columnCount + column
                        if index < (tr.count) {
                            VStack {
                                MovieCellView(index: index, tr: tr, qualities: $qualities)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: State variables cannot be modified on the view, so this does not work

Comment: @Higherous did you actually try this code? State variables are designed to be modified from the body of the view, that is their main purpose. They cannot be modified from _outside_ the view, but they can be modified from inside it.

Comment: Are you really sure? Just try minimal lightweight code with the same usage
`struct ContentView: View {
    @State var myVar: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        myVar = 5
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .padding()
    }
}`
State variables can only be changed from functions like onAppear

Comment: @Higherous that's completely wrong, not sure why you got this idea from. I am completely sure that changing `State` variables from inside the body of a view is safe.

Comment: This is impossible. I dropped the code above, try it yourself
Pastebin https://pastebin.com/qiQ1Y79z